# Jmeter- how to extract data from redirection

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have any API. When i hit this API by jmeter, ir redirects to server A(do some processing), then redirects to B, and finally redirects to C( which is a HTML page).

In view result tree, i only get he final HTML response. Is there some way, by which i can see the request response to server A & B

Comment: Any feedback on answers, if OK it should be accepted and upvoted

Comment: still, same result. Actually A-->B is a server to server call.

Answer (score 2):

Just uncheck "Follow redirects" option in HTTP Request

[image]

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

You will then need to emit yourselft the requests by Using A Regexp Extractor to extract from Header the URL and then call it.

Comment: Thanks! you saved me. I was struggling from long time