# Count redirects in jmeter

Tags: redirect, jmeter

At the moment im usig **HTTP request** sampler with 'Follow Redirects' *enabled* and want to keep it that way. As a secondary check besides assertion i want to count the number of redirects as well, but i dont want to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823194/jmeter-how-to-extract-data-from-redirection) solution.

Is there a way when i can use only 1 HTTP sampler and a postprocessor (beanshell for now) and fetch this information? Im checking [SamplerResult documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) , but cant find any method which would give back this information for me.

Comment: Do you want to count the redirects for only one sampler?

Comment: For every sampler separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard [Groovy is new black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) moreover [users are encouraged to use JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy() function since JMeter 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as Beanshell performs not that well so you can count the redirects as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of your HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   int redirects = 0;
   def range = new IntRange(false, 299, 400)
   prev.getSubResults().each {
       if (range.contains(it.getResponseCode() as int)) {
           redirects++;
       }
   }

   log.info('Redirects: ' + redirects)
   ```

Once you run your test you will be able to see the number of occurred redirects in *jmeter.log* file:

[image: JMeter Groovy Count Redirects]

Answer (score 2):

Add the following [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) as a child of your sampler:

- Apply to: **Main sample and sub-samples**
- Field to check: **Response code**
- Regular Expression: **(\d+)**
- Template: **$1$**
- Match No.: **-1**

Then add a BeanShell Post Processor also as a child of the sampler and add the following to the script area:

```
int matchNr = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("MyVar_matchNr"));// MyVar is the name of the variable of the above regular expression extractor
int counter = 0;
for(i=1; i <= matchNr; i++){
    String x = vars.get("MyVar_"+i);
    if(x.equals("302")){
        counter = counter + 1;
    }}
log.info(Label + ": Number of redirects = " + String.valueOf(counter));// The output will be printed in the log like this(BeanShell PostProcessor: Number of redirects = 3 ) so you might want to change the name of the beanshell post processor to the same name of your sampler.
```

Then you can see the number of redirects for the sampler in the log.