# How to filter HTTP request by error code

Tags: jmeter

I run a Jmeter script and getting 200 and 302 HTTP response code in result.
There is no idea to get information to which HTTP request responding 302 HTTP code.
is there in setting or plugin to get better understanding to categorized HTTP request by HTTP response code.

Also need to why 302 error occur and should I need to do something in JMeter Script

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[302 Response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) means you that the API you are hitting is redirecting you to another one, this will happen if the **follow redirects** check box in your HTTP sampler is checked.

You can add **View result tree listener** at the same lever of your thread group, and from this listener you see the response code for each sampler at the **sampler result** tab.

Comment: In View result tree listener I have to move each result to view response code .how can I Filter HTTP sampler request by HTTP Response Code.e.g. if I search through 302 the all those request got filtered whose response code is 302..Is There any way to do this?

Comment: You can check this answer, add the beanshell to all of your samplers and you can check what samplers are getting 302 in the log https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322351/count-redirects-in-jmeter?noredirect=1#comment79609529_46322351